# Floating radius box inside a bordered container

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to float a rounded rectangle (created using CSS) both left and another box right inside a centered container.  When I do so, the left box isn't not aligned with the left, and the right box is flowing over the container.  I've tried a million things, but I'm too new to CSS to solve this...

Here is my code:

```css
#container {
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-width:960px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

#branding {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:black;
  z-align:1000;
}

#logo {
  background-image:url("images/google-logo-small.png");
  height:69px;
  width:200px;
  margin:15px 0 0 10px;
  float:left;
  z-align:1001;
}

#toparea {
  margin:20px 0px 0 0;
  float:right;
  color:white;
  z-align:1001;
}

#toparea ul li {
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0 30px 20px 0;
}

#topcontent {
  width:100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:inherit;
  margin:10px 0px 0px 10px;
  z-align:1000;
}

#blockone {
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 10px 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width:45%;
  height:200px;
  background-color:gray;
  float:left;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:black;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#blockone p {
  font-size:20px;
  color: white;
  padding:20px 0 0 20px;
}

#blocktwo {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width:45%;
  height:200px;
  float:right;
  background-color:gray;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:black;
  margin:10px 0 0 0;
}

#blocktwo p {
  font-size:20px;
  color: white;
  padding:20px 0 0 20px;
}

#footer {
  clear:both;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background-color:gray;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="branding">
      <div id="logo"></div>
      <div id="toparea">
        <ul>
          <li>Content</li>
          <li>Content2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="topcontent">
          <div id="blockone">
          <table>
            <tr><td>field</td><td input="textbox" /></tr>
            <tr>
          </table>
          </div>

          <div id="blocktwo">
          <p>this is more text</p></div>
          </div>
      <div id="footer">Some more copy</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `margin` set on `#topcontent` is what is pushing that container off the screen. Remove the left/right margin and you're set. You're not seeing a horizontal scroll bar because the wrapping container is set to overflow: hidden. http://jsfiddle.net/Fkj4L/

Answer (score 1):

set the margin 0 to id topcontent

```
#topcontent {
width:100%;
height: 300px;
background-color:inherit;
margin:0;
z-align:1000;
}
```

[see demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/pEe74/1/)